# Splitting CSV at each header and passing each split sequentially

Tags: java, groovy, split, integration

I am trying to split the below CSV File based on occurrence of "Header" i.e. for the payload below , two separate CSV should pass after the application of Script. Any help for this case using Groovy/JavaScript would be helpful.

```
Header|1000|SA|20210902|20210902|header text-01|USD| Line|6101200|WTAppUpload-02|2000|40005001| Line|1110100|WTAppUpload-03|2000| Line|6101200|WTAppUpload-04|1500|40005002| Line|1110100|WTAppUpload-05|1500| Line|6101200|WTAppUpload-06|1500|40005003| Line|1110100|WTAppUpload-07|1500| Header|1100|SA|20210902|20210902|header text-02|USD| Line|6101200|WTAppUpload-12|2000|40005001| Line|1110100|WTAppUpload-13||2000| Line|6101200|WTAppUpload-14|1500|40005002| Line|1110100|WTAppUpload-15|1500| Line|6101200|WTAppUpload-16|1500|40005003| Line|1110100|WTAppUpload-17|1500|
```

Only the last value for each Split is getting displayed by below script, we require all to be populated respectively in each split. Can someone please suggest.

```
def body= message.getBody(String.class);
String[] value = body.split("Header");

def arrayLength = value.size();

message.setHeader("value",arrayLength);
for(int i=1; i<=arrayLength-1;i++) {         
def str = value[i];
message.setBody(str);
}
return message;
```

Comment: That's not CSV. CSV is ***comma*** separated values. I've noticed a disturbing trend of people referring to any delimited text file as a CSV file.

Comment: The `split` breaks the string into three parts: an empty string before the first "Header", the part after the first and before the second, and the part after the second. The for loop starts at 1 so it skips the empty string, and it goes up to length - 1, so it should include both the non-empty parts. You need to add debugging details showing what you're getting, and what you're expecting to get.

Comment: Note: `i<=arrayLength-1` instead of `i < arrayLength` is a non-idiomatic way of writing the loop condition.

Comment: Wait. Each time around the loop, you do `message.setBody(str)`. That is obviously going to replace the body each time, leaving only the last one on the message. How are you expecting this to include more than one string in the message body? Your problem has nothing to do with splitting strings.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a simpler way but this should do what you want for the sample string you sent

where `toMod` is your string

```
def split = toMod.splitEachLine("\\|") { it }

int counter = 0
split.each {
    def tmpMap = [:]
    def val = it.trim()
    if (val.contains("Header") || val.contains("header")) {
        counter++
    } else {
        tmpMap[counter] = val
    }
    arr.add(tmpMap)
}

def finalArr = []

for (int i = 1; i <= counter; i++) {
    def tmp = []
    arr.each {
        if (it[i] != null) {
            tmp.add(it[i])
        }

    }
    finalArr.add(tmp)
}
```

Output:

```
[[1000, SA, 20210902, 20210902], [USD, Line, 6101200, WTAppUpload-02, 2000, 40005001, Line, 1110100, WTAppUpload-03, 2000, Line, 6101200, WTAppUpload-04, 1500, 40005002, Line, 1110100, WTAppUpload-05, 1500, Line, 6101200, WTAppUpload-06, 1500, 40005003, Line, 1110100, WTAppUpload-07, 1500], [1100, SA, 20210902, 20210902], [USD, Line, 6101200, WTAppUpload-12, 2000, 40005001, Line, 1110100, WTAppUpload-13, , 2000, Line, 6101200, WTAppUpload-14, 1500, 40005002, Line, 1110100, WTAppUpload-15, 1500, Line, 6101200, WTAppUpload-16, 1500, 40005003, Line, 1110100, WTAppUpload-17, 1500]]
```